# Create Test Class for Outbound Emails

Tags: apex, trigger

I am having trouble sending a trigger into my production. I have currently written the following trigger to send an email to a customer whenever a service report is created:

```
trigger sendServiceReport on ServiceReport (after insert) {
    
    for(ServiceReport sr : trigger.new) {
        
        list<ServiceAppointment> sa = new list<ServiceAppointment>([
            select id, AccountId, ContactId, Send_Report__c, WorkTypeId, Payment_Type__c, Status
            from ServiceAppointment 
            where id = :sr.ParentId]);
        list<Account> account = new list<Account>([select id, Name, RecordTypeId from Account where id = :sa[0].AccountId]);
        list<Contact> contact = new list<Contact>([select id, Name, Email from Contact where id = :sa[0].ContactId]);
        
        List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> attachments = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>{};
        List<ContentVersion> documents = new List<ContentVersion>{};
        //get service report as a file (ContentVersion record)
        documents.addAll([
            select Id, Title, FileType, VersionData, isLatest, ContentDocumentId
            from ContentVersion
            where isLatest = true and title like : sr.ServiceReportNumber limit 1]);
        
        for (ContentVersion document: documents) {
                Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                attachment.setBody(document.VersionData);
                String fileName = contact[0].Name + '.pdf';
                attachment.setFileName(fileName);
                attachment.setContentType('application/pdf');
                attachments.add(attachment);
            }

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailOffice = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
        
        if(sa[0].Send_Report__c == true) { //send service report to customer if they want it
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            EmailTemplate emailTemplate = new EmailTemplate();
            OrgWideEmailAddress owea = new OrgWideEmailAddress();
            
            if(sa[0].WorkTypeId == '08q4C000000L6SZQA0') { //Filter Change Appointment ('08q0e000000KylTAAS' in production / '08q4C000000L6SZQA0' in sandbox)
                if(account[0].RecordTypeId == '01236000000SKk5AAG') { //EWS Record
                    emailTemplate = [select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'EWS Filter Change Report'];
                    owea = [select id, DisplayName from OrgWideEmailAddress where DisplayName = 'EWS Service'];
                } else { //GWT Record '01236000000SKkAAAW'
                    emailTemplate = [select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'GWT Filter Change Report'];
                    owea = [select id, DisplayName from OrgWideEmailAddress where DisplayName = 'GWT Service'];
                }
                //sendTo.add('test@elitewateroftexas.com'); //send copy of all filter change reports to Office Admin
            } else if(sa[0].WorkTypeId == '08q4C000000L8KWQA0') { //Service Appointment ('08q0e000000KylAAAS' in production / '08q4C000000L8KWQA0' in sandbox)
                if(account[0].RecordTypeId == '01236000000SKk5AAG') { //EWS Record
                    emailTemplate = [select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'EWS Service Report'];
                    owea = [select id, DisplayName from OrgWideEmailAddress where DisplayName = 'EWS Service'];
                } else { //GWT Record '01236000000SKkAAAW'
                    emailTemplate = [select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'GWT Service Report'];
                    owea = [select id, DisplayName from OrgWideEmailAddress where DisplayName = 'GWT Service'];
                }
                //sendTo.add('test@elitewateroftexas.com'); //send copy of all service reports to Service Manager
            } else {
                emailTemplate = [select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'Test'];
                owea = [select id, DisplayName from OrgWideEmailAddress where DisplayName = 'GWT Service'];
            }
                      
            email.setTargetObjectId(contact[0].id);
            email.setWhatId(sa[0].id);
            email.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.id);
            email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.id);
            
            email.setFileAttachments(attachments);
            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
        }
        
        //add email for Office to send copy to
        sendTo.add('test@elitewateroftexas.com'); //send all emails to Accounting Department
        emailOffice.setToAddresses(sendTo); 
            
        if(sa[0].WorkTypeId == '08q4C000000L6SZQA0') { //Filter Change Appointment ('08q0e000000KylTAAS' in production / '08q4C000000L6SZQA0' in sandbox)
            if(account[0].RecordTypeId == '01236000000SKk5AAG') { //EWS Record
                emailOffice.setSubject('*' + sa[0].Payment_Type__c + '* EWS Filter Change Ticket');
            } else { //GWT Record '01236000000SKkAAAW'
                emailOffice.setSubject('*' + sa[0].Payment_Type__c + '* GWT Filter Change Ticket');
            }
        } else if (sa[0].WorkTypeId == '08q4C000000L8KWQA0') { //Service Appointment ('08q0e000000KylAAAS' in production / '08q4C000000L8KWQA0' in sandbox)
            if(account[0].RecordTypeId == '01236000000SKk5AAG') { //EWS Record
                emailOffice.setSubject('*' + sa[0].Payment_Type__c + '* EWS Service Ticket');
            } else { //GWT Record '01236000000SKkAAAW'
                emailOffice.setSubject('*' + sa[0].Payment_Type__c + '* GWT Service Ticket');
            }
        }
        
        String body = 'This report was generated for ' + account[0].Name + ' by ' + userinfo.getName();
        emailOffice.setHtmlBody(body);

        emailOffice.setFileAttachments(attachments);
        
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {emailOffice});
        
        //Change the status of Service Appointment
        if(sa[0].Status == 'Dispatched') {
            sa[0].Status = 'Onsite';
            update sa[0];
        } else if(sa[0].Status == 'Onsite') {
            sa[0].Status = 'Completed';
            update sa[0];
        }
    }
}
```

I have written the following test code:

```
@isTest
private class sendServiceReportTest {
    @isTest static void sendReportTrue() {
        //Create Account
        Account account = new Account();
        account.Name = 'Test Account';
        account.RecordTypeId = '01236000000SKk5AAG';
        insert account;
        account = [select id from Account where id = :account.id];
        
        //Create Contact
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.AccountId = account.id;
        contact.FirstName = 'Test';
        contact.LastName = 'Contact';
        contact.email = 'test@test.com';
        insert contact;
        contact = [select id from Contact where id = :contact.id];
        
        //Create Work Type
        WorkType workType = new WorkType();
        workType.Name = 'Filter Test';
        workType.DurationType = 'Minutes';
        workType.EstimatedDuration = 30;
        insert workType;
        workType = [select id from WorkType where id = :workType.id];
        
        //Create Work Order
        WorkOrder workOrder = new WorkOrder();
        workOrder.AccountId = account.id;
        workOrder.WorkTypeId = workType.Id;
        insert workOrder;
        workOrder = [select id from WorkOrder where id = :workOrder.id];
        
        //Create Service Appointment
        Date d =System.today();
        DateTime dtStart = datetime.newInstance(d,Time.newInstance(08,00,00,00));
        DateTime dtEnd = dtStart.addHours(1);
        
        ServiceAppointment sa = new ServiceAppointment();
        //sa.AccountId = account.id;
        sa.ParentRecordId = workOrder.Id;
        sa.Status = 'Assigned';
        sa.EarliestStartTime=dtStart;
        sa.SchedStartTime=dtStart;
        sa.DueDate=dtEnd;
        sa.SchedEndTime=dtEnd;
        sa.ContactId = contact.id;
        sa.Send_Report__c = true;
        insert sa;
        sa = [select id from ServiceAppointment where id = :sa.id];
        
        //Create Service Report 
        ServiceReport sr = new ServiceReport();
        sr.DocumentBody = Blob.valueOf('Test Content') ;
        sr.DocumentContentType ='application/pdf';
        sr.DocumentName='Test';
        sr.ParentId = sa.Id;
        
        Test.startTest();
            insert sr;
            Integer emailInvocations = Limits.getEmailInvocations();
        Test.stopTest();
        
        system.assertEquals(2, emailInvocations, 'Two emails should be sent');
    }
    
    @isTest static void sendReportFalse() {
        //Create Account
        Account account = new Account();
        account.Name = 'Test Account';
        account.RecordTypeId = '01236000000SKk5AAG';
        insert account;
        account = [select id from Account where id = :account.id];
        
        //Create Contact
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.AccountId = account.id;
        contact.FirstName = 'Test';
        contact.LastName = 'Contact';
        contact.email = 'test@test.com';
        insert contact;
        contact = [select id from Contact where id = :contact.id];
        
        //Create Work Type
        WorkType workType = new WorkType();
        workType.Name = 'Filter Test';
        workType.DurationType = 'Minutes';
        workType.EstimatedDuration = 30;
        insert workType;
        workType = [select id from WorkType where id = :workType.id];
        
        //Create Work Order
        WorkOrder workOrder = new WorkOrder();
        workOrder.AccountId = account.id;
        workOrder.WorkTypeId = workType.Id;
        insert workOrder;
        workOrder = [select id from WorkOrder where id = :workOrder.id];
        
        //Create Service Appointment
        Date d =System.today();
        DateTime dtStart = datetime.newInstance(d,Time.newInstance(08,00,00,00));
        DateTime dtEnd = dtStart.addHours(1);
        
        ServiceAppointment sa = new ServiceAppointment();
        //sa.AccountId = account.id;
        sa.ParentRecordId = workOrder.Id;
        sa.Status = 'Assigned';
        sa.EarliestStartTime=dtStart;
        sa.SchedStartTime=dtStart;
        sa.DueDate=dtEnd;
        sa.SchedEndTime=dtEnd;
        sa.ContactId = contact.id;
        sa.Send_Report__c = false;
        insert sa;
        sa = [select id from ServiceAppointment where id = :sa.id];
        
        //Create Service Report 
        ServiceReport sr = new ServiceReport();
        sr.DocumentBody = Blob.valueOf('Test Content') ;
        sr.DocumentContentType ='application/pdf';
        sr.DocumentName='Test';
        sr.ParentId = sa.Id;
        
        Test.startTest();
            insert sr;
            Integer emailInvocations = Limits.getEmailInvocations();
        Test.stopTest();
        
        system.assertEquals(1, emailInvocations, 'An email should be sent');
    }
    
    @isTest static void dispatchedToOnsite() {
        //Create Account
        Account account = new Account();
        account.Name = 'Test Account';
        account.RecordTypeId = '01236000000SKk5AAG';
        insert account;
        account = [select id from Account where id = :account.id];
        
        //Create Contact
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.AccountId = account.id;
        contact.FirstName = 'Test';
        contact.LastName = 'Contact';
        contact.email = 'test@test.com';
        insert contact;
        contact = [select id from Contact where id = :contact.id];
        
        //Create Work Type
        WorkType workType = new WorkType();
        workType.Name = 'Filter Test';
        workType.DurationType = 'Minutes';
        workType.EstimatedDuration = 30;
        insert workType;
        workType = [select id from WorkType where id = :workType.id];
        
        //Create Work Order
        WorkOrder workOrder = new WorkOrder();
        workOrder.AccountId = account.id;
        workOrder.WorkTypeId = workType.Id;
        insert workOrder;
        workOrder = [select id from WorkOrder where id = :workOrder.id];
        
        //Create Service Appointment
        Date d =System.today();
        DateTime dtStart = datetime.newInstance(d,Time.newInstance(08,00,00,00));
        DateTime dtEnd = dtStart.addHours(1);
        
        ServiceAppointment sa = new ServiceAppointment();
        //sa.AccountId = account.id;
        sa.ParentRecordId = workOrder.Id;
        sa.Status = 'Dispatched';
        FSL.GlobalAPIS.addStatusTransition('Dispatched', 'Onsite');
        sa.EarliestStartTime=dtStart;
        sa.SchedStartTime=dtStart;
        sa.DueDate=dtEnd;
        sa.SchedEndTime=dtEnd;
        sa.ContactId = contact.id;
        insert sa;
        sa = [select id from ServiceAppointment where id = :sa.id];
        
        //Create Service Report 
        ServiceReport sr = new ServiceReport();
        sr.DocumentBody = Blob.valueOf('Test Content') ;
        sr.DocumentContentType ='application/pdf';
        sr.DocumentName='Test';
        sr.ParentId = sa.Id;
        
        Test.startTest();
        insert sr;
        Test.stopTest();
        
        sa = [select Status from ServiceAppointment where id = :sa.id];
        System.debug('Status after trigger fired: ' + sa.Status);
        
        System.assertEquals('Onsite', sa.Status);
    }
    
    @isTest static void onsiteToCompleted() {
        //Create Account
        Account account = new Account();
        account.Name = 'Test Account';
        account.RecordTypeId = '01236000000SKk5AAG';
        insert account;
        account = [select id from Account where id = :account.id];
        
        //Create Contact
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.AccountId = account.id;
        contact.FirstName = 'Test';
        contact.LastName = 'Contact';
        contact.email = 'test@test.com';
        insert contact;
        contact = [select id from Contact where id = :contact.id];
        
        //Create Work Type
        WorkType workType = new WorkType();
        workType.Name = 'Filter Test';
        workType.DurationType = 'Minutes';
        workType.EstimatedDuration = 30;
        insert workType;
        workType = [select id from WorkType where id = :workType.id];
        
        //Create Work Order
        WorkOrder workOrder = new WorkOrder();
        workOrder.AccountId = account.id;
        workOrder.WorkTypeId = workType.Id;
        insert workOrder;
        workOrder = [select id from WorkOrder where id = :workOrder.id];
        
        //Create Service Appointment
        Date d =System.today();
        DateTime dtStart = datetime.newInstance(d,Time.newInstance(08,00,00,00));
        DateTime dtEnd = dtStart.addHours(1);
        
        ServiceAppointment sa = new ServiceAppointment();
        //sa.AccountId = account.id;
        sa.ParentRecordId = workOrder.Id;
        sa.Status = 'Onsite';
        FSL.GlobalAPIS.addStatusTransition('Onsite', 'Completed');
        sa.EarliestStartTime=dtStart;
        sa.SchedStartTime=dtStart;
        sa.DueDate=dtEnd;
        sa.SchedEndTime=dtEnd;
        sa.ContactId = contact.id;
        insert sa;
        sa = [select id from ServiceAppointment where id = :sa.id];
        
        //Create Service Report 
        ServiceReport sr = new ServiceReport();
        sr.DocumentBody = Blob.valueOf('Test Content') ;
        sr.DocumentContentType ='application/pdf';
        sr.DocumentName='Test';
        sr.ParentId = sa.Id;
        
        Test.startTest();
        insert sr;
        Test.stopTest();
        
        sa = [select Status from ServiceAppointment where id = :sa.id];
        System.debug('Status after trigger fired: ' + sa.Status);
        
        System.assertEquals('Completed', sa.Status);
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that this only covers 74% of the code and I'm not sure what else I could test to cover the remaining portion. I haven't been able to find a way to test if the sent email's contents are correct such as subject, body, etc. if this is even possible. This is my first apex trigger so I'm not sure how to increase the test code's covergae.

Comment: Not being rude, but I don't think you want this in production yet. Queries in loops ,hard coded Ids, logic in trigger etc.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply. I get how queries in a loop is bad (I hadn't thought about that implication) but how would I resolve that? How would I not use logic in a trigger but still maintain the logic of specifying certain contents for the email?

Comment: The last one ("logic in trigger") is only a recommendation/best practice, the remaining items are all basic "Apex 101" type problems. You can read [this trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) for a good starting point, and check out our *[tag:bulkification]* tag; you're not the first to be unaware of bulkification best practices, nor will you be the last. Looking at your code, I would wager that if you fixed the bulkification problems, you'd also get well above 75% coverage as well.